# How can I use the browser with python without Selenium

Tags: python, google-chrome, firefox, browser, automation

I'm looking for a way to control the normal web browser (import web browser). i have been working with selenium for a few months but would like to work without selenium
Unfortunately there is no documentation for this or is that not possible?

Comment: "Normal web browser" what do you mean by this? Chrome, firefox, explorer, edge, duckduckgo, etc. are all "normal" browsers. What is it you're actually trying to do? A [mcve] would help

Comment: The browser doesn't matter, I'm currently using Chrome and Firefox for my automations with Selenium as a module, but I would like to work with this module https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html without having to access selenium again have to, I wonder how can I enter classes, id or xpath in this symbol in order to enter a user or a password, for example

Answer (score 2):

You can use pyautogui, if your using python.
To install it use: `pip install pyautogui`
To import it into your code: `import pyautogui`
pyautogui documentation: https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: @Community Is this fine?

Comment: @K1NGS For what it's worth, you can't respond to the Community bot.
I think a small example code snippet would be OK.